# solving a matrix ODE

Tags: differential-equations, asymptotics

I am trying to solve an ODE which looks like this: $t^2*f'(t)+K.f(t)+t*G.f(t)=0$ for $K$ and $G$ some matrices 2*2 and $f$ is a vector of functions in variable $t$.

```
ClearAll[k, g, f, x, y];  
k = {{0, 0}, {2, 0}};
g = {{-1/2, 0}, {0, 1/2}};
f[t_] = {x[t], y[t]};
sol = DSolve[t^2* f'[t] + k . f[t] + t*g . f[t] == {0, 0}, f[t], t]
```

I get a solution:

```
{{x[t] -> Sqrt[t] C[1], 
  y[t] -> C[2]/Sqrt[t] - (2 C[1] Log[t])/Sqrt[t]}}
```

But when I change `k` to `k = {{0, 1}, {2, 0}}`, `DSolve` seems not to apply, as the equation probably does not have explicit analytical answer. I am interested in the asymptotic behavior of the solutions when $t$ goes to zero (the norm of the solution should have growth some power of $t$ and/or some power of logarithm). I tried `AsymptoticDSolveValue`, which did not give me the any answer and `NDSolve` for which I get error like "`1/4.6671*10^307` is too small  to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost".

Comment: "DSolve does not give any answer" - that typically means that DSolve cannot find an explicit analytical answer to your equation. Do you have reasons to believe that an explicit analytical solution should exist? Can you try if `NDSolve` can find one a numerical solution?

Comment: You are right, I edited the question.